# How can I edit the uncompressed jQuery library to put up my own requirement in a function?

Tags: jquery, cdn

I have a task where I have to include a specific requirement in a function.
The CDN code of jQuery looks a bit difficult to understand compared to the regular jQuery we use.

The issue is that when I focus on something like an `input` box it should not just focus on it but also return its `top` and `left` position. This functionality is supposed to be included in the CDN file. Then using a regular program I must call it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function(){
        $("input").css("background", "lightblue");
        var p = $( "input" );
        var position = p.offset();
        $("div").text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );       
    });
});
```

Comment: Your title seems completely unrelated to what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly never ever amend the source of a library. If you do, it ties you to that specific version of the code. If the author updates the library they make break the additions you made. If you want to create additional functionality, create your own extension methods or prototypes.

That said, to do what you require you simply need to amend your code to only reference the element which raised the event. To do that use the `this` keyword within the handler function. Try this:

```js
$("input").focus(function() {
  var $input = $(this).css("background", "lightblue");
  var position = $input.offset();
  console.log("left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input />
```

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, what you are trying to do is not recommended. Unless the library is not maintained, then you could get a fork from its github repo and then add your changes so so that you could maintain it.

In this case, jQuery is a highly maintained project where editing it's source to add your own code will be disastrous. Instead, use the provided plugin architecture to add more functionality to the existing code.

Go through the official documentation to get an overview of this feature.

[How to create a basic jQuery plugin.](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)